# Google assistant action, no function URL

Tags: google-cloud-functions, dialogflow-es, actions-on-google, firebase-cli

i would like to create an action project. I have an issue when i run `firebase deploy --only functions`.

Before i run: `npm install -g firebase-tools`, `firebase login`, `firebase init`, `npm install actions-on-google`, `npm install`

Everything is working and it says: Deploy complete. But it doesnt deliver me the function URL in the CMD. Also when i look it up over here : https://console.firebase.google.com/.../functions/list it doesnt show me the URL.

Do you have any idea what i am doing wrong?
That is the Tutorial i am doing:
https://developers.google.com/actions/tools/fulfillment-hosting

Best regards
Luca

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: I do not have any code yet. My index.js only contains `const functions = require('firebase-functions');`

Comment: You need to define an HTTP function before a deployment will give you a url.  You can't deploy "nothing" and expect something to be created.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to export a function otherwise Firebase cannot run/deploy it. You can view some great code examples on how to make Actions on the Google Assistant with Firebase [here](https://developers.google.com/actions/samples/github).

The following code should help you get started.

```
const {dialogflow} = require('actions-on-google');
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

const app = dialogflow({debug: true});


exports.myFunction = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```